# Added dependency still showing class or interface expected in case of ViewModel in Android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-livedata, android-databinding

I have searched on the web I found class or interface expected questions but in my case I added the dependency for ViewModel in kotlin and when trying to import the package for the same I was getting class or interface expected. I manually tried to importing the package of viewModel but no gain.

Please BEFORE MARKING THE QUESTION AS DUPLICATE read my question.

I am adding some screenshots of plugins, dependencies I added and the error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUBbs.png)

PLUGINS : (I even tried replacing 'kotlin-android-extensions' with 'kotlin-parcelize' with implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.3.1" but it didn't solve anything)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOt5n.png)

DEPENDENCIES :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtSJ6.png)

kotlin version I am using :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z2Eln.png)

Comment: Please post the relevant code/configuration - not screenshots.

Comment: Did you accidentally create a Java file? I can only reproduce your errors by writing your Kotlin code in a Java file.

Comment: Oh, yes. I created .java file. Thank you so much. Håkon Schia

Answer (score 1):

SOMEBODY DELETED MY ANSWER.

So, posting it again.

I accidently created a .java file, so, I was getting this error.